# Is AWS Step Functions service HIPAA Compliant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

HIPAA compliant services are listed in AWS HIPAA Compliance Whitepaper:
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_HIPAA_Compliance_Whitepaper.pdf

Unfortunately, AWS Step Functions isn't listed in this whitepaper.
But if I use HIPAA compliant services in Step Functions, is that configuration HIPAA compliant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use *any* AWS service in an account designated as a HIPAA account, but you should only process, store and transmit PHI in HIPAA-eligible services.

So, if you use Step Functions to orchestrate your workloads, without actually processing, storing, or transmitting any PHI in Step Functions then you should be fine.

The [HIPAA Eligible Services Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-eligible-services-reference/) page has the latest list of HIPAA-eligible services.

Comment: If I have a task with only one Lambda Function that processes some PHI, am I fine? :)

Comment: Lambda is HIPAA-eligible, but you have to get data into the Lambda function, of course, and potentially data out of it. If any of that data is PHI then the source/destination are subject to the same rules too.

Comment: Ok. 
My function's input data is just S3 bucket and key name that don't contain PHI. Lambda gets file from S3, processes PHI and transmits it to another HIPAA-eligible service by HTTPS protocol. 
So such AWS Step Functions configuration can be HIPAA compliant?

Comment: As you've outlined the architecture, it seems reasonable to me that you should be able to process PHI. Note that if you plan to do this on AWS, then you need to accept the AWS BAA.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 31, 2018, you can use AWS Step Functions to orchestrate distributed applications and workflows containing healthcare-related information, including personal health information (PHI) of users, and information subject to U.S. Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA). See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/aws-step-functions-is-now-a-hipaa-eligible-service/.